# What online reference atlases/maps would be useful to point out geographical features?

Tags: discussion, references, general-reference

(Not exactly sure how well this plays with the intent for [references](/questions/tagged/references) and [general-reference](/questions/tagged/general-reference) tags on Meta here, but it seems like a worthwhile question.  Or at least one that's been bugging me for a while)

It's common to either post, or get requests for, sources to make a particular point.  This runs the gamut from wikipedia to reputable news outlets and online articles.

However, a fair bit of politics, especially when it comes to international relations, deals with geography.  At that point it will sometimes be necessary to point to *maps*.  And this is what I am asking about here.  The only options I am aware of are:

- modern online maps, either Google Maps or its competitors.  The problem here is that they are very road-oriented and don't focus all that much on either national boundaries or physical features.  For example, in a post I claimed that Azerbaijan did not have a border with Turkey.  But apparently they do, if very small.  However, as soon as you zoom in to see it on Google maps, it's hard to see borders as roads and cities dominate.  Same things happens on my tablet's map apps.
- looking for "online maps" typically gives you either dated or very imprecise atlas-style images of limited resolutions, say 1000x1000 that don't serve well as references either.

With that in mind, what would be possible sources for geographical info references to provide in posts that need it?  Especially as pertains to large-scale, non-road, data?  Like either boundaries or physical terrain characteristics?

Ideally, I'm thinking of something like those old, but pretty detailed, atlases we used to have in geography classes.

p.s. don't focus too much on Turkey-Azerbaijan that was just an example.

Comment: In this particular case, [the Wikipedia article on the Azerbaijan-Turkey border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijan%E2%80%93Turkey_border) has some usable maps.

Comment: Nice.  But... without knowing I had to look for that special case, Google Maps led me to believe that there was no border.  So what references should we use to cover the general cases?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Try [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/). Searching for "Azerbaijan-Turkey border", for example, takes to the location. Borders are the yellow lines.